# Python and BeautifulSoup - trouble specifying fields in a div with <dt> and <dd> tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use python3 and beautifulsoup4 to pull data from an online school listing.  Here's how the data variable is defined:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "school_data"})
```

And here's the structure of how each list element from g_data[] comes out:

```
<div class="school_data">
    <h4 class="cyan_header">Coop Tech<br/></h4>
    <dl>
        <dt>School Type: </dt>
        <dd>Academic</dd>
        <dt>Another Heading: </dt>
        <dd>etc.</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

In starting to try to pull out the fields, I started with this:

```
for item in g_data:
    try:
        print(item.contents[0].find_all("h4",{"class": "school_data"})[0].text)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        schoolType = item.contents[1].find("dt", text="School Type: ")
        print(schoolType.find_next_sibling("dd").text)
    except:
        pass
```

For the school name (the h4 tags) I expected the above to print the text from the first h4 tag within the first list element in "contents" but it didn't return anything. I *did* eventually get it to print the text from the h4 tags just by doing this:

```
print(item.contents[0].text)
```

This has limitations though...why didn't the original work?

For the schoolType part (the second try in the loop), I get a "TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments".  I read up on that a bit, but having seen others recommend this, I'm not sure why the error.  I suspect I'm doing other stuff wrong as well... for example, when I tried simply printing out item.contents[1] to debug, I got a bunch of blank lines.

Any help?  Further along, I'll create variables for the data and write it to a csv.  New to python and stackoverflow so thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the text from the children inside the *dl* tags that are siblings of the previous *h4 cyan_header* you can just extract the child tags from the dls:

```
h = """<div class="school_data">
    <h4 class="cyan_header">Coop Tech<br/></h4>
    <dl>
        <dt>School Type: </dt>
        <dd>Academic</dd>
        <dt>Another Heading: </dt>
        <dd>etc.</dd>
    </dl>
</div>"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

h4s = soup.select("div.school_data h4.cyan_header")
for h4 in h4s:
    print([child.text for child in h4.find_next("dl").children if isinstance(child, Tag)] )
```

Which would give you:

```
[u'School Type: ', u'Academic', u'Another Heading: ', u'etc.']
```

Why you get `find() takes no keyword arguments"` is because `item.contents[1]` is a string not a Tag so you are actually calling `str.find`.

Also if you just want a single tag returned you should use *find* not *find_all*, find will give you the one match, the first.

You can also extract all the dd tags and dt tags using the dl tag:

```
h4s = soup.select("div.school_data h4.cyan_header")
for h4 in h4s:
    dl = h4.find_next("dl")
    dds = dl.find_all("dd")
    dts = dl.find_all("dt")
    print(dds)
    print(dts)
```

Which would give you:

```
[<dd>Academic</dd>, <dd>etc.</dd>]
[<dt>School Type: </dt>, <dt>Another Heading: </dt>]
```

What you use completelty depends on what exactly it is you want and how the rest of the html is structured, one other thing you should never do is use a blank except without at the very least printing/logging any error.

Comment: Thanks, @Padraic.  I wasn't really getting how .contents worked, so this is very helpful.  That last for loop looks great and is way more efficient than what I was doing as long as as all the items in the dds list are consistent in the source data.  I could append the h4 text to it I guess if I want all the data in one list.

Comment: No prob,  without seeing the full html it is difficult to give an exact approach but hopefully it will get you  a little closer